How To Convert A Polygon Area Into Square Foot In Java / Spring / PostGIS
I'm having a problem where I'm trying to figure out how to turn the Polygon area into surface area measurements like square foot, hectares, or even acres for example.
I have dependencies for Hibernate Spatial and JTS Core:
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.locationtech.jts</groupId>
    <artifactId>jts-core</artifactId>
    <version>${jts.version}</version>
</dependency>

Here's some code I've already written...
Field entity with entity fields that contains the area field, which is a Polygon and the size, which I'm trying to calculate...
@Entity(name = "field")
@Table(name = "field")
public class Field {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "area", columnDefinition = "geometry(Polygon, 4326)", nullable = false)
    private Polygon area;

    @Column(name = "center", columnDefinition = "geometry(Point, 4326)")
    private Point center;

    @Column(name = "size")
    private Double size;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_farm_id")
    private Farm farm;
}

Simple repository for the field...
@Repository
public interface FieldRepository extends JpaRepository<Field, Long> {
}

Interface for the FieldService that contains the response DTO class I want to return and the publicFarmId parameter, which is used instead of showing the primary key field to the users...
public interface FieldService {

    CreateFieldResponseDto createNewField(UUID publicFarmId, FieldDto fieldDto);
}

The overriden createNewField method in the FieldServiceImpl implementation class with helper methods to turn the coordinates from the fieldDto into a Polygon, calculate the center coordinates of the Polygon.
@Override
public CreateFieldResponseDto createNewField(UUID publicFarmId, FieldDto fieldDto) {

     Farm farm = farmRepository.findByPublicId(publicFarmId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new FarmNotFoundException("Farm not found"));

    Field newField = new Field();

    newField.setName(fieldDto.getName());
    newField.setArea(convertToPolygon(fieldDto.getCoordinates()));
    newField.setCenter(calculateCenter(newField.getArea()));
//    newField.setSize(calculateFieldSize(newField.getArea()));
    newField.setFarm(farm);

    fieldRepository.save(newField);

    return fieldMapper.INSTANCE.toCreateFieldResponseDto(newField);
}

//--------------------------------------------|
// HELPER METHODS FOR CREATING A NEW FIELD... |
//--------------------------------------------|

private Polygon convertToPolygon(List<List<List<Double>>> coordinates) {

    GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory();

    LinearRing shell = geometryFactory.createLinearRing(
            convertToCoordinateArray(coordinates.get(0))
    );

    LinearRing[] holes = new LinearRing[coordinates.size() - 1];

    for (int i = 1; i < coordinates.size(); i++) {
        holes[i - 1] = geometryFactory.createLinearRing(
                convertToCoordinateArray(coordinates.get(i))
        );
    }

    return geometryFactory.createPolygon(shell, holes);
}

private Coordinate[] convertToCoordinateArray(List<List<Double>> coordinatesList) {

    Coordinate[] coordinates = new Coordinate[coordinatesList.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < coordinatesList.size(); i++) {
        List<Double> point = coordinatesList.get(i);
        coordinates[i] = new Coordinate(point.get(0), point.get(1));
    }

    return coordinates;
}

private Point calculateCenter(Polygon polygon) {

    GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory();

    return geometryFactory.createPoint(polygon.getCentroid().getCoordinate());
}

Our controller class...
@PostMapping("/{publicFarmId}/fields")
public ResponseEntity<Object> createField(
    @PathVariable UUID publicFarmId, @RequestBody FieldDto fieldDTO
) {
    CreateFieldResponseDto createdField = fieldService.createNewField(publicFarmId, fieldDTO);

    return ResponseHandler.generateResponse(
            HttpStatus.CREATED,
            "success",
            "Field created successfully.",
            new LinkedHashMap<>() {{
                put("name", createdField.name());
                put("coordinates", createdField.coordinates());
                put("center", createdField.center());
                put("size", createdField.size());
                put("unitOfMeasurement", "metric"); // CODE THIS LATER !!!
            }}
    );
}

The field DTO class that is the request object containing the name of the field a farmer can give and the coordinates we use to construct the Polygon. The coordinates are inside a list of lists, so that we can also create Polygons with holes as well...
public class FieldDto {

    private String name;
    private List<List<List<Double>>> coordinates;
}

I'm pretty lost to what could be the most optimal solution to a problem like this, should I calculate the Polygon size in Java code, or does PostGIS have methods already that help with turning Polygon's into some area sizes with SQL, for example, saving the Polygon into the database, and immediately running some UPDATE query to do that in the database? Not sure about performance, but that's the only thing what I came up with.
All help is much appreciated about this problem and on how to improve the existing code, because this sounded so simple at first (just turning a Polygon into an area size), but I'm not sure how this should be done?
Thank you!

Looks like the area will be returned in whatever units (squared) you used for your coordinates.  I.e. if your coordinates are in feet, the area is returned in square feet, etc.

PostGIS can compute the area using ST_Area function. What you need to know is you cannot get a useful area using 4326 projection (geometry type). This returns area on flat and distorted map, which is meaningless and cannot be converted to square feet.
You either need to use Geography type, or convert to a suitable projection (which depends on the location on globe you are working with). Here is small demo:
postgres=# select st_area('polygon((1 1, 2 1, 2 2, 1 1))');
 st_area 
---------
     0.5
(1 row)

postgres=# select st_area('polygon((1 1, 2 1, 2 2, 1 1))'::geography);
      st_area      
-------------------
 6153961068.605661
(1 row)

The first number 0.5 is meaningless, the second is area in square meters and can be trivially converted to square feet.
